# not a valid zip file on reading excel file in 2 goroutines

Tags: excel, go

I have main function for reading excel file. I use [excelize](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize). this main function is calling function A using goroutine and pass the required channels. and this function A calling function B using goroutine twice but with different parameter to read different sheet. I want to have first goroutine finish first then go to second goroutine. But i got error `not a valid zip file`

My main function

main.go

```golang
func main(){
 f, _ := os.Open("./report.xlsx")
 defer f.Close()

 filename := f.Name()
 data := make(chan string, 2)
 errors := make(chan error)

 go BuildData(f, data, errors)
}
```

build_data.go

```golang
func BuildData(f io.Reader, datac chan string, errorc chan error) {
 sheet1 := make(chan []string, 2)
 sheet1err := make(chan error)
 var sheet1ct [][]string
 sheet1Name := "Sheet1"
 go ReadExcel(f, sheet1, sheet1err, sheet1Name)

    for {
        select {
        case data, cl := <-sheet1:
            if !cl {
                done = true
                break
            }
      sheet1ct = append(sheet1ct, data)
        case erru = <-sheet1err:
            if erru != nil {
                errorc <- erru
                done = true
            }
        }

        if done {
            break
        }
    }

  // wait for sheet 1 finish reading
    for !done {
        continue
    }

  sheet2 := make(chan []string, 2)
  sheet2err := make(chan error)
  sheet2Name := "Sheet2"
  go ReadExcel(f, sheet2, sheet2err, sheet2Name)

    for {
        select {
        case data, cl := <-sheet2:
            if !cl {
                done = true
                break
            }
      validRecord := makeValidRecord(data, sheet1ct)
      datac <- validRecord
        case erru = <-sheet2err:
            if erru != nil {
                errorc <- erru
                done = true
            }
        }

        if done {
            break
        }
    }
}

func makeValidRecord(data []string, sheet1 [][]string) string {
  // make valid record, return a string
}
```

read_excel.go

```golang
func ReadExcel(file io.Reader, rowChan chan []string, errChan chan error, sheetName string) {
    f, err := excelize.OpenReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        errChan <- err
        return
    }

    rows, _ := f.GetRows(sheetName)
    for _, row := range rows {
        rowChan <- row
    }

}
```

From the log i produce it actually can read sheet 1 and put all the data into `var sheet1ct [][]string`. but when it come to sheet 2 i got error `not a valid zip file` even though it is same excel file.

Kindly need your help. Thanks!

Comment: You can’t read the same file twice concurrently, you would get random portions of the file. If you want to read serially, you can’t read from the end of the file, you need to seek to the start

Comment: i can't seek to io.Reader @JimB

Comment: You have an `os.File` which can seek, or use the `io.ReadSeaker` interface, or open the file multiple times, or read it once and buffer the result - whatever works for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
reportBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./report.xlsx")
reader := bytes.NewReader(reportBytes) 
excelize.OpenReader(reader)
```

i.e. don't pass that file reference around, read in all the bytes and make a `bytes.NewReader` from them when you need them.